# WooCommerce affiliate link with multi URLs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I currently run a site that has products in WooCommerce. The product URL links to an affiliate site and the custom functions.php script appends the affiliate ID to the external URL using this code:

```
       *  Custom Add Affiliate link to Buy Product
 */
 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url', 'custom_product_add_to_cart_url', 20, 2 );
function custom_product_add_to_cart_url( $add_to_cart_url, $product ){
    if( $product->is_type('external') )
        $add_to_cart_url .= '/?affiliateID-1';

    return $add_to_cart_url;
}
/**
 *  End Custom Add Affiliate link to Buy Product
```

What I am hoping to do is add another affiliate site to this and depending on which URL is in the `$add_to_cart_url` would determine which affiliate link is appended.

So currently if the `$add_to_cart_url` is `www.siteA.com` the link generated is `www.siteA.com/?affiliateID-1`

I want to make a change so that:

if the `$add_to_cart_url` is `www.siteA.com` the link generated is `www.siteA.com/?affiliateID-1`
OR
if the `$add_to_cart_url` is `www.siteB.net` the link generated is `www.siteB.net/?affiliateID-2`

I assume I need some form of "if `$add_to_cart_url` is this, then append with this, else append with this" however I'm not sure how I need to adjust my existing code to do this.

```
   $add_to_cart = $someValueHere;

if ($add_to_cart == $siteAValue){

    $add_to_cart_url .= '/?affiliateID-1';

} else if ($add_to_cart == $siteBValue){
    
    $add_to_cart_url .= '/?affiliateID-2';
}
    

return $add_to_cart_url;
```

}

Where should I be entering the specifics of each of the 2 URLs it needs to check against? Maybe if for example, Facebook.com is affiliate 1 and Microsoft.com is affiliate 2? Would you be able to show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url', 'custom_product_add_to_cart_url', 20, 2 );
function custom_product_add_to_cart_url( $add_to_cart_url, $product ){
    if( !$product->is_type('external') ){
        return $add_to_cart_url;
    }
    if (strpos($add_to_cart_url, 'www.sitea.com/') === 0) {
        $add_to_cart_url .= '/?affiliateID-1';
    } elseif (strpos($add_to_cart_url, 'www.siteb.com/') === 0) {
        $add_to_cart_url .= '/?affiliateID-2';
    }

    return $add_to_cart_url;
}
```

Comment: Such a complete code?                                                                                               
                                                             add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url', 'custom_product_add_to_cart_url', 20, 2 );
function custom_product_add_to_cart_url( $add_to_cart_url, $product ){
if (strpos($add_to_cart_url, 'www.sitea.com/') === 0) {
    $add_to_cart_url .= '/?affiliateID-1';
} elseif (strpos($add_to_cart_url, 'www.siteb.com/') === 0) {
    $add_to_cart_url .= '/?affiliateID-2';
}

return $add_to_cart_url;

}

Comment: @Bbbycks111 I updated for the complete function & filter

Comment: /?affiliateID-1 and /?affiliateID-2  Is it possible to add these parameters to the beginning of url?     affiliateID-2/www.sitea.com

Comment: You can write `$add_to_cart_url = 'affiliateID-1/' . $add_to_cart_url;`